# Unity3D Save and Load data from an XML file doesn't work

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I'm building my first prototype for multi-game sharing achievement system. It means there's two or more games using one shared achievement data. I'm storing the data in an .xml file, for now the xml only contains coins data.

So i want my program to load and modify the amount of coins from it.

This is My XML :

```
<Achievement><Coins>800</Coins></Achievement>
```

My Code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

public class XMLTest : MonoBehaviour {

string Filelocation, FileName;

private Text CoinsText;

public int Coins;
public int Price;
void Start () {
    CoinsText = GameObject.Find("CoinsText").GetComponent<Text>();
    Filelocation = "E:/Projek/Projek Pak Suprapedi/XML Test/";
    FileName = "Coins.xml";
}

public void WriteToXML()
{
    XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    if(File.Exists(Filelocation + FileName))
    {
        XmlDoc.Load(Path.Combine(Filelocation, FileName));
        XmlNodeList AchievementList = XmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Achievement");
        foreach(XmlNode node in AchievementList)
        {
            if(node.Name == "Coins")
            {
                node.InnerText = Coins.ToString();
            }
        }
        XmlDoc.Save(Path.Combine(Filelocation, FileName));
    }
}

public void LoadFromXML()
{
    XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    if(File.Exists(Filelocation + FileName))
    {
        XmlDoc.Load(Path.Combine(Filelocation,FileName));
        XmlNodeList AchievementList = XmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Achievement");
        foreach(XmlNode node in AchievementList)
        {
            if(node.Name == "Coins")
            {
                Coins = int.Parse(node.InnerText);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void Buy()
{
    Coins -= Price;
}

public void GetMoney()
{
    Coins += Price;
}

void Update()
{
        CoinsText.text = "Your Coins : " + Coins.ToString();
    }
}
```

I'm assigning the public void to a button so i can modify the coins then save or load it. But it seems that load and save function won't do anything, nothing happen to xml file.

I will deploy my game to Android platform, but I don't know if this method would work, would it ?

Comment: Side note: `Filelocation + FileName` and `Path.Combine(Filelocation, FileName)` likely will produce different results...

Comment: so which one do I need to choose ??

Comment: @RisalFajarAmiyardi, on the MDSN, you can see the behavior is slightly altered depending on what you pass in. A large part would really be dependant on what you are combining. Personally, I find `Path.Combine` a bit "safer". You can read about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @DangerZone okay so I will use `Path.Combine`. Does it work on Android platform ?

Comment: Use Sqlite, much better than using xml files.

Comment: You Filelocation = "E:/Projek/Projek Pak Suprapedi/XML Test/" will bring you many problems if you deploy it later on mobile devices.

Comment: @David Sqlite ? Is it compatible with flash too ??

Comment: @David that file path is just for testing, i will change it later once my script has been fixed

Comment: @RisalFajarAmiyardi, sqlite is irrelevant with flash.

Comment: @David I will research about sqlite first, cause my project using unity app and flash app in one device. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question. I've found the problem.

so the problem is :

```
XmlNodeList AchievementList = XmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Achievement");
```

I'm replacing it with

```
XmlNodeList AchievementList = XmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Coins");
```

And it works !!

I think you can understand what is the problem now